# XSLT 2.0 in command line: Directory problems

Tags: xml, xslt, command-line

I have a XSL Stylesheet called "EAndSST2ARXML.xsl" in the XSLT/XSLT directory. I have several XML-Files to transform in the XSLT/InputFiles directory. The Output Files should be generated in the XSLT/OutputFiles directory. The Output files should have the same name as the input files, only the extension should change from .xml to .arxml. So far I achieve this with the following command in the XSL-File:

```
<xsl:variable name="filename"><xsl:value-of select="functx:substring-before-if-contains(base-uri(),'.xml')" /></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}.arxml">
```

And I run the transformation with following commandline command:

```
java.exe -Xms512M -Xmx512M  -jar C:\Users\bal2LR\Desktop\XSLT\Parser\saxon9he.jar   -t  -repeat:1 -o:C:\Users\bal2LR\Desktop\XSLT\OutputFiles  -s:C:\Users\bal2LR\Desktop\XSLT\InputFiles\  C:\Users\bal2LR\Desktop\XSLT\XSLT\EAndSST2ARXML.xsl
```

The transformation runs, but there are 2 issues:

1. the generated files are in the XSLT\InputFiles directory instead of the XSLT\OutputFiles directory. (I guess it's because of the commands in the XSL Stylesheet)
2. If I run the transformation a second time, also the .arxml-files are getting transformated a second time. But I want only to transform .xml files. If the output-file already exists, it should get overwritten.

Somebody knows how to solve these issues? I thought about a batch file, with several commands, but I have no experience with it so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
<xsl:variable name="filename"><xsl:value-of select="functx:substring-before-if-contains(base-uri(),'.xml')" /></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}.arxml">
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="filename" select="functx:substring-before-if-contains(tokenize(base-uri(), '/')[last()],'.xml')" />
  <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}.arxml">
```

Comment: Thank you very much Martin Honnen! It worked out perfectly. But I still don't understand what was the problem?

Comment: My suggestion puts a relative URI in the form of `foo.arxml` as the `href` attribute that can then be resolved relative to the output folder you provided on the command line while your approach computes an absolute URI (e.g. `file:///C:/Users/bal2LR/Desktop/XSLT/InputFiles/foo.arxml`) which obviously then forces Saxon to output the file exactly there in that input folder.

Comment: All the time the issues with relatives and absolute paths. I should take more care about it! thank you!!